# How to remove files without certain extension?

Tags: linux, shell

How to remove all files without the `.txt` and `.exe` extensions recursively in the current working directory? I need a one-liner.

I tried:

```
find . ! -name "*.txt" "*.exe" -exec rm -r {} \
find -type f -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*\.(txt|exe)$'
```

Comment: I think this can help you :
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/remove-all-files-directories-except-for-one-file

Comment: Your one liner commands are worked ?

Comment: they didn't work. the link didn't help either.

Comment: @R.Naired Please see my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this.

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.exe" ! -name "*.txt" -exec rm {} \;
```

The above command will remove all the files other than the .exe and .txt extension files in the current directory and sub directory recursively.

Comment: This would be faster using `+` instead of `\;` (as pointed out by Benjamin W.'s answer), because then `rm` would only be run once total rather than once for each file.

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU `find` with the `-delete` action:

```
find . -type f ! \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.exe' \) -delete
```

And if not:

```
find . -type f ! \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.exe' \) -exec rm -f {} +
```

using [`-exec ... {} +`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files) to execute `rm` as few times as possible, with the arguments chained.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```sh
rm -f $(find . -type f ! \( -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.exe" \))
```

This will first recursively find all files that do not end with `.txt` or `.exe` extensions, and then delete all of these files.

Comment: Your command removes `.txt` files, which the querist wants to keep.

Comment: rm -rf $(find . -type f ! \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.exe' \))